# internal error when publishing a stream

Tags: ios, opentok, tokbox

I'm using the IOS SDK.

Trying to Publish a stream and getting

```
Error Domain=OTSessionErrorDomain Code=2000
```

Code:

```
session = OTSession(apiKey: kApiKey,
                    sessionId: kSessionId,
                    delegate: self)

var error: OTError?
session.connect(withToken: kToken,
                error: &error)

let settings = OTPublisherSettings()
settings.cameraResolution = .high
settings.cameraFrameRate = .rate30FPS

guard let publisher = OTPublisher(delegate: self, settings: settings) else { return }

session.publish(publisher, error: &error)
```

I'm getting the error on `session.publish`

Any idea what can be the problem?

I cant find any list of internal error options.

When i run the example SimpleVideo app with the same credentials everything works good.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be able to get it working by very little chance because publishing won't be successful until a client has successfully connected to a session. The correct steps should be:

- Attempt to connect to a session
- Did connect to a session
- Attempt to publish to the connected session

So, you can't call `publish` right after calling `connect` method. Instead, you should do publishing in `sessionDidConnect:`. That is the callback delegate method to ensure that a client has connected a session successfully.